# Bulk internal links redirect method in static site

Tags: php, html, mysql, .htaccess, redirect

I have a static site consisting of about 1500+ pages. Each one of those HTML pages has an internal link (I mean coded on the page itself) that I want to replace with a new one.

But, it is not possible to edit all those pages as there are thousands of them.

Here is an example:

- Say I have a page `www.example.com/page.html`
- There is a hyperlink on that page which directs to `www.abc.com`
- I want this link replace/redirect with `www.xyz.com` instead of `www.abc.com`

I already have a MySQL table in which I have all the current links vs the new links in two columns.

Is there a way to redirect all these links by using the `.htaccess` file, PHP and MySQL? If it is possible then what would be the code look like?

Comment: @Epodax Yes, I did. But, I got confused and failed. I came here for help and never expected to get this type of reply. Thank you for that You were so kind and helpful. By the way, I figured out a way to resolve this and added that as an answer already. I hope you would find some "lacks of goodness" there too and kindly suggest me to improve my effort. Keep your current positive attitude toward other people's weakness and this way you will be the one who would make this world a better place. I like the way you think. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to change all the links using this script.

```
<?php
require_once("connection.inc.php");

function get_value($file){
    //$html = file_get_contents($file,true);
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($file);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $nodes = $xpath->query('//a/@href');
    foreach($nodes as $href) {
        return $href->nodeValue;            // echo current attribute value
        //$href->nodeValue = 'new value';   // set new attribute value
        //$href->parentNode->removeAttribute('href');  // remove attribute
    }
}

function put_value($file,$pattern){
    //$html = file_get_contents($file,true);
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($file);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $nodes = $xpath->query('//a');
    $nodes->item(0)->setAttribute("href",$pattern);
    $dom->save($file);
}

$dir   = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__);
$flat  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
$files = new RegexIterator($flat, '/\.html$/i');

foreach($files as $file) {
    $value=get_value($file);
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT new_links FROM site WHERE current_links='$value'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)==1){
        $value_orginal = mysql_result($query,0);
        put_value($file,$value_orginal);
        echo "The ".$file." has changed to ".$value."</br>";
    }
    else{
        die("die baby die :)");
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use htaccess redirection
[Redirect to a Different URL using .htaccess](http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-htaccess.phtml)

Comment: Thank you brother for your help. :-) This link is much more simpler than others.  I will now try to do that with htaccess.